# How do I configure the mouse event behaviors

Tags: compiz, mouse, window-manager

I've just installed 14.04 and cannot find the **configuration tool** to control how mouse clicks are acted on by the window manager, and then optionally passed to the application.

I want to set the same traditional **Unix behavior** of:

- 'focus follows mouse': done.
- 'never auto-raise': done.
- 'raise when click on border or title': Can't find the option.
  A middle button click on the tile does lower a window - but traditionally it would also raise the bottom window.

I can set 'raise on any click' - but that is absolutely hopeless when you are trying to copy text from a lower window.

Comment: Hmmmm My Compiz installatoin was doing the "raise on title click" But I reset the settings, so I can only say that it is possible from Compiz :/

Answer (score 1):

I do that setup from the CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm) because the default Ubuntu preferences does not include such super advance settings.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then start it with (from a command line or create a launcher icon):

```
ccsm
```

That opens settings, click on **General » General Options** then on the **Focus & Raise Behaviour**. That opens the following window which you can play with. As you can see, I have all 3 checkboxes unselected. It is really deadly to have them set, as you mentoined.

[image]

By the way, you can also fix that from the command line (Especially when an update of the OS decides to kill your settings!):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 "['<Alt>F1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 "['<Alt>F2']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 "['<Alt>F3']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-move "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings begin-resize "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-group "['disabled']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings lower "['<Alt>F6']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings raise "['<Alt>F7']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences auto-raise "false"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode "sloppy"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences raise-on-click "false"
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 2
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 2
```

In case you want to add actions with the mouse the buttons, replace the key name with one of these: "Button1" (left), "Button2" (middle), "Button3" (right). If you have such a mouse, you may have access to "Button4" and "Button5" too.

This kind of a script will save you hours of re-setting your preferences over and over again.

Comment: Do you know how to set Alt+Left_click to raise the window being clicked in (and then start moving it) and Alt+Right_click to lower the window? I'm used to these shortcuts but I can't find how to enable them in `ccsm`

Comment: In "General Options", then tab "Key Bindings". It is shown in the screenshot, but of course... you have to know that the name on the left corresponds to the button to click to get there.

Comment: Right, I'm not sure how I missed it yesterday. Thanks a lot. Compiz sure is customizable!